# Maven access to gcloud

Tags: java, maven, gcloud

In my project we are migrating our old public Maven repository to a gcloud storage. The change to pom.xml file was rather simple:

```
<extension>
    <groupId>com.gkatzioura.maven.cloud</groupId>
    <artifactId>google-storage-wagon</artifactId>
    <version>1.5</version>
</extension>
...
<repository>
    <id>local</id>
    <url>gs://XXX</url>
</repository>
```

On my computer, I am able to successfully login using "gcloud auth login" and I am able to upload files via UI and gsutil. However, when the Maven build attempts to download the files from the storage, I get:

> [ERROR] Could not establish connection with google cloud
>   com.vorstella.shade.com.google.cloud.storage.StorageException:
>   Anonymous caller does not have storage.objects.list access to XXX.

Other team members installed the gcloud exactly as I have and they do not have any problems downloading the Maven dependencies. I've been trying to figure this out for a couple of days and haven't made any progress.

Answer (score 7):

I just figured this out. Somehow, my gcloud credentials were "legacy". I executed the following:

```
gcloud auth application-default login
```

and it replaced the legacy credentials file in my `~/.config/gcloud` with a different file. After that, I was able to build with maven.